# Change image button in Hover with Bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, hover, multiple-columns

is lot of time I'm trying to have 3 columns button in bootstrap that change image in Hover.
I have tryed everything but nothing work, all the solution I've found broken the lines of Bootstrap or cause me lot of problem.
Can someone help me to do this? http://s3.postimg.org/j1yibn3pv/Schermata_2015_08_04_alle_11_35_20.png

Please, I'm desperate!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with the code, what tags for buttons do you?

Comment: js is javascript? Is it compatible with every browsers? can you explane me how to do it?

Comment: jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ - include your html, css and js if have one in the appropriate blocks, save the fiddle and provide a link to it in your task. Thus we'll be able to see what problems you're experiencing

Comment: I don't know how to doit, I had tryed with background image and with two img with position absolute but are not working.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 <div class="container">
  <div id="box-servizi" class="section-shadow">

   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="promozioni">
    <a href="#" title="Scopri tutte le nostre Promozioni">
     <img class="section-shadow img-responsive normal" src="img/box-servizi/promozioni.jpg" alt="Immagine Promozioni Lodigiani Concessionaria" title="Scopri tutte le nostre Promozioni!" />
     <img class="img-responsive hover" src="img/box-servizi/promozioni-h.jpg" alt="Immagine Mouse Hover Promozioni Lodigiani Concessionaria" title="Scopri tutte le nostre Promozioni!" />
    </a>
   </div><!-- /promozioni -->
  </div><!-- /box-servizi -->
 </div><!-- /container -->
<!-- /BOX SERVIZI -->
```

```html
#box-servizi {
 background: #ffffff;
 margin: 50px 0px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#box-servizi>div {
 margin-top: 25px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 padding-right: 50px;
}

#box-servizi>div>a>img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* transitions */
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
         -o-transition: all .4s ease;
            transition: all .4s ease;
}


#box-servizi>div>a>img.normal{
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* IE stuff */
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
#box-servizi>div>a>img.hover{
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE stuff */
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* hover */
#box-servizi>div>a:hover>img.normal{
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#box-servizi>div>a:hover>img.hover{
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: your code is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/et3rp7w8/1/ . the image changes on hover.

Comment: I think is not good to set a fixed height and its broken the lines of Bootstrap..

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```css
/* ==========================================================================
   SERVIZI
   ========================================================================== */

#servizi-bottom {
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#servizi-bottom>.container>a>div {
 padding: 2.205% 0%;
}

#servizi-bottom h3 {
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #ffffff;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 font-style: italic;
}

.servizi-button {
 border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}


/* Promozioni
   =================================== */

#box-promozioni {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/promozioni.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-promozioni {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/promozioni-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-promozioni h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Servizi
   =================================== */

#box-servizi {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/servizi.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-servizi {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/servizi-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-servizi h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Test Drive
   =================================== */

#box-testdrive {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/testdrive.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

a:hover #box-testdrive {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/testdrive-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-testdrive h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Contatti
   =================================== */

#box-contatti {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/contatti.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

a:hover #box-contatti {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/contatti-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-contatti h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Tagliando
   =================================== */

#box-tagliando {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/tagliando.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

a:hover #box-tagliando {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/tagliando-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-tagliando h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

/* Officina
   =================================== */

#box-officina {
 background: transparent url("../img/box-servizi/officina.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

a:hover #box-officina {
 background-image: url("../img/box-servizi/officina-hover.jpg");
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px white;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover #box-officina h3 {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   -moz-opacity: 0;
   -khtml-opacity: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- !BOX SERVIZI -->
 <div class="row" id="servizi-bottom">
  <div class="container">

   <a href="#" title="Scopri tutte le nostre Promozioni">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-promozioni">
     <h3>promozioni</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-promozioni -->

   <a href="#" title="Tutto ciò che offriamo">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-servizi">
     <h3>servizi</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-servizi -->

   <a href="#" title="Tutto sui nostri Test Drive">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-testdrive">
     <h3>test drive</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-testdrive -->


   <a href="#" title="Scopri come Contattarci!">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-contatti">
     <h3>contatti</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-contatti -->

   <a href="#" title="Tagliando">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-tagliando">
     <h3>tagliando</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-tagliando -->

   <a href="#" title="Le nostre Officine">
    <div class="servizi-button col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="box-officina">
     <h3>officina</h3>
    </div>
   </a><!-- /box-officina -->



  </div><!-- /container -->
 </div><!-- /row -->
<!-- /BOX SERVIZI -->
```

What do you think?